# Convergence in the $L^1$-norm. Computation of measure of a certain symmetric difference

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $E\subset \Bbb R^d$ be measurable, and let $\chi_E$ be the characteristic function:
$$\chi_E(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x\in E\\0,&x\not\in E\end{cases}$$

I want to show that for $f_h(x)=x-h$ that $\chi_E\circ f_h\to \chi_E$ as $h\to 0$ in the $L^1(\Bbb R^d)$-norm.

My approach so far is:
$$|\chi_E\circ f_h - \chi_E|=|\chi_{E-h} - \chi_E| = \begin{cases}1,& x\in (E-h),x\not\in E\\ 0,& x\in (E-H)\cap E\\1,& x\in E,x\not\in E-h\end{cases}$$
$$=\chi_{(E-h)\Delta E}$$
where $A\Delta B$ is the symmetric difference $A\Delta B = A\cap B^c \cup A^c \cap B$.

Thus:
$$\|\chi_E\circ f_h-\chi_E\|=\int \chi_{(E-h)\Delta E)} = m((E-h)\Delta E)$$
and it's 'clear' that $(E-h)\Delta E= \emptyset$ for $h=0$, so I feel like I can conclude $$\lim_{h\to 0}\|\chi_E\circ f_h - \chi_E\|=\lim_{h\to 0} m((E-h)\Delta E)=m(\emptyset)=0,$$
but this doesn't seem rigorous, and I can't seem to actually write down what $m((E-h)\Delta E)$ is.

How does one properly conclude that $\chi_E\circ f_h\to \chi_E$ as $h\to 0$?

Comment: First of al this statement does not make sense for an arbitrary set $E$. You have to assume that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable. Secondly, this result cannot be proved by simple computations. You will have to approximate $E$ by 'nice' sets. This result is quite standard and a proof can be found in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I did intend for $E$ be measurable. I was doing this as a step before showing it's true for simple functions, and then using density of simple functions in $L^1(\Bbb R^d)$ to get the result in general.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy By nice sets, you mean in terms of cubic covers? Lastly, I can get such an argument done with simple computations for the case of $f\circ d_\delta \to f$ as $\delta \to 1$ (in $L^1$) where $d_\delta(x)=\delta x$ is a dilation. So I feel like it's not unreasonable that they would be sufficient here.

Comment: Yes. A more general result is $\int |f(x)-f(x-h)|dx \to0$ as $h \to 0$ for any integrable function $f$ and this is proved by approximating $f$ by continuous functions with compact support.